# How can I get images with specific tags using Flickr's getRecent API method?

Tags: android, json, rest, url, flickr

I'm trying to use [Flickr's getRecent](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getRecent.htm) method to get recently uploaded photos with the tag "building". How do I build the URL to do this?

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=5423dbab63f23a62ca4a986e7cbb35e2&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

Currently I'm using this URL to make a call to the getRecent method, but I want to add a tag parameter. I see from the documentation that "tags" is supported in the "extras" parameter, but I am unsure how to use this in the url. I'm trying things like:

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=5423dbab63f23a62ca4a986e7cbb35e2&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&tag=building

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=5423dbab63f23a62ca4a986e7cbb35e2&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=tags,building

but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas how to use the getRecent method to pull specific tags?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you tell which library are you using ? in retrofit you can pass param data in query

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh yes, I am using Retrofit, but even before I get to the point of building the query I need to know how to build the query. I don't even know what needs to be appended to the URL to get this to work how I want. Seems like Flickr's API is very confusing.

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: I'm not using this in code yet. I am simply trying to figure out what the append to the url so I can specify the tags of the images that are returned. Once I know what the url parameter is I shouldn't have any trouble converting that to a query param in Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a simple example that you need to do in your retrofit interface API method, just take query for your tag whatever value you want to append in your URL.

```
@GET("your_url_path_here") 
Call<_photos_data_object> groupList(@Query("tag") String tag);
```

you can refer to the retrofit document from the source.
http://square.github.io/retrofit/